# Spring boot security roles per entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

My application has currently two types of users: **Admin** or **Normal** user.

The application has several projects: 100 or more. Per project the user has a different role like project owner, client, etc...

I'm now figuring out the best way to put those subroles in place. 
Because in my services I want to use `PreAuthorise("hasRole('OWNER')")` so that only the right people can execute an update or whatever.

What I was trying now was giving every project a list of users that are working on it with a roles (project owner, client, etc...) when I login via Spring Security I retrieve the user and fetch all the projects where he is part of and then I add roles as follows `ROLE_PROJECTNAME_OWNER` or `ROLE_PROJECTNAME_CLIENT`.

The thing is that I can't use the `HASROLE` because there are a lot of projects so I can't annotate in advance which projects there are to allow a method call in my service layer. I also can't just add `OWNER` because then I don't know in which project. So I'm a little bit stuck here how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

Define your own service to manage access with user/project/role and call this service directly on your @PreAUthorize.

Have a look to : https://dreamix.eu/blog/java/implementing-custom-authorization-function-for-springs-pre-and-post-annotations

Comment: In my case a user could be part of many groups. I was able to use this to authorize the user based on the group and any related group object they were accessing by passing that ID in the @PreAuthorize annotation and running a quick DB check for their permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you separate your users and the groups they form part of, from the roles and services they can access.

There are various ways you can do this, but one approach is to have the central authentication framework provide you the groups of the user once he performs authentication.

Now within each service, there will be a mapping between groups and roles. The roles are application specific, the authentication service or the other applications do not care about them. You might store this mapping in the individual application's database, or in a simple configuration file (maybe simply in `application.yaml` of the specific application).

Your groups currently are `Admin` and `Normal` but you could have others. A user could also be a member of multiple groups. So in application 1 you could say that `Admin` users can do role 1, role 2, role 3, while `Normal` users can only do `role 1`. Again it is many to many. This is something your `UserDetails` instance would carry once it recognizes the authenticated user and his groups, which are then mapped to roles as part of your Spring Security configuration. You will then be able to do `PreAuthorise("hasRole('OWNER')")` etc. on your services.

This way, if you add more users, you just put them in the right groups to give them access to the individual services. If you want to create new profiles, instead of just `Admin` and `Normal`, or special groups, you just do it once and update the configuration of the individual application to recognise that group if it is relevant to it (remember the user can be a member of multiple groups, so you don't even need each application to know about each group).

I don't know what mechanism you are using for single sign on authentication. But in spirit of microservices and minimal sharing between applications, you could actually put the groups as scopes in your token (if you are using JWT for example). This way the application receiving the token not only knows that the user was authenticated but knows the groups of the user without even making a query to any other system.

This architecture you will have is shown in the picture.

[image: Microservice Security Model]

Each use case (service method annotated with `@PreAuthorise`) will have a role. 
Each user will be associated with a number of groups the authentication system will provide. (For example groups in Active Directory). Upon receiving the authentication information of the user, the groups will be mapped to the roles specific to the application and populated in the `UserDetails` Spring Security object. Each annotated method will then get the application specific roles (not the global groups).

This gives you the flexibility to add as many groups as you like that can have the same application role.

Comment: Thanks for your help already. But I dont see how this can work with different roles on projects. I have a project A where I am owner and then project B I’m just a client. How is it working then? Because I cant put hasRole owner on top because it Will always succes because I have the owner role because I’m owner in project A?

Comment: You have to create a different group for the different profiles you have. If all Admin users are Owners in Project A, then you map group Admin -> role Owner. If Admin  is irrelevant for Project A, then you have to create a new group 'Project A Owners'. If the group has more cross-cutting concerns across applications (like 'senior managers' can see reports from Project A, B, and C), you will have a different mapping of the group's rights per project.

Comment: So I will have a Iist of owner Users, list of projectManager Users and so on that's what you mean by groups right? Andt hen when I enter a restcontroller and I do a method on my service I check if the authenticated user is in the list of for example owner roles with @PreAuthorise?

Comment: Yes. Well you can do it as you wish really. You have to think, does the system doing the authentication need to know about each individual system of the 100 or more, or is there some logical grouping you can do of your users based on business processes. So your authentication system is just saying the user gave me the right password and here are the groups he is in. Each of the 100 systems can then say, if the user is a member of group 'Sales Reps' then I allow him to do take these roles to allow him to do these operations. 'Sales Reps' could be a group cross cutting across systems or not.

Comment: I added a diagram and some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks again for all your effort. I'm now trying to implement this. So as I know understand I just create all my different roles (client, project manager, ...) once in the app and those roles have a many to many relationship with users. When the user logs in I give him all the roles he is part of. But then I'm stuck because when calling a project service or a company service the roles can be different. I'm confused how to give him the right role. Because in company A he is the owner but in B not. And in this system he will be a owner for B to. Because the user has owner role from project A?

Comment: I don't know enough about your case unfortunately. Will you be giving granular rights per project (so each user by 100 projects?!) or do you want to group them and give roles to each group, then when a new user comes you just add him to the right groups?