# Spring: Roles, authorities and permissions for entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Good afternoon.
How can I configure permissions and roles for a user relative to a specific controller for a specific entity (something similar to RBAC/ABAC) within one application without usage of different OAUTH2 services?

Example:

App has **global USER roles: ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN**.

Also there's entity named **Project**. There may be many Projects that USER may be a member of. 
There're some **Project USER roles: PROJECT_ADMIN, PROJECT_EDITOR, PROJECT_USER**.
Each project role can have their own permissions (authorities) like add user to project, edit project and so on. All role configs are stored in 'project_roles' and 'project_permissions' tables.

As I understood it can be implemented through PreAuthorize annotation, but how can current global user be matched to project role?

```
@PreAuthorize("@projectService.hasPermission('create_project', #projectEditRequest.id)") // How to pass GlobalUserID?
@PostMapping
public ProjectDto create(@RequestBody @Validated ProjectEditRequest projectEditRequest) {
   ...
   ...
}
```

Maybe there're examples of such case implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Analog questions:

[Spring boot security roles per entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395662/spring-boot-security-roles-per-entity)

[Roles connected with entities in Java Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317648/roles-connected-with-entities-in-java-spring) (without answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all OAuth2 is not the right way to do this at all, since you are talking about fine grained, entity-based authorizations. Something like this you would implement with a library like [Spring ACL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html). Your authorization model would then usually reside in the same database as your secured entities and Spring Security would grant requested CRUD operations by the ACL (Access Control List) and the current spring security (user) context.

From OAuth2 you would basically just use the subject/user as the owner of existing ACL entries.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I have two questions.
1) As I understood ACL doesn't support jwt auth token generation. So it should be implemented together, am I right? Maybe you can share examples?
2) If I don't have lots of entities (not more that two), does it make sense to use ACL? Maybe it's more convenient to build dependencies between user entities manually? Can I make complicated permissions in ACL, like one entity depends from other and there's global rule for both entities

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by generating JWT with ACL. You have your ACL definitions IN the service that needs to be secured. E.g. you have a service that handles user profiles, it would have a datebase that contains the profile entitities as well as the ACL mappings about who owns what profile or who may or may not delete, update or create profiles .I don't see how you would have to create a JWT at this point.
And yes, when it comes to complex permission models, ACL is definitely what you want. I'd be surprised if you can think of a complexity that ACL wouldn't be able to cover.

Comment: I suggest you google the documentation, maybe you can find some good examples too. I remember when I tried to play around with it, there weren't many good and extensive tutorials, since implementing good and powerful authorization logic, especially with tools like ACL, is not something you would call trivial.